# SailsJS error "`undefined` should be a [x] (instead of [x], which is a [x])"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

So I'm getting this really anoying error whenever I tried to save a date in my mongodb via SailsJS. Im doing a simple post. I do understand what the given error means but I just cant understand what I'm doing wrong to get this error.

The error:

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "2 attributes are invalid",
  "model": "BuddyAvailability",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "start": [
      {
        "rule": "datetime",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a datetime (instead of \"Mon Sep 19 2016 20:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)\", which is a object)"
      }
    ],
    "end": [
      {
        "rule": "datetime",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a datetime (instead of \"Mon Sep 19 2016 22:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)\", which is a object)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My module:

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'buddyAvailability',
    attributes: {
        buddy: {
            model: 'user'
        },
        start: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        end: {
            type: 'datetime'
        }
    }
};
```

The data I post:

```
{
    buddy:"57dfe57839053b3500d1cdec"
    end:"2016-09-19 22:00"
    start:"2016-09-19 20:00"
}
```

I've tried using type: date and type: datetime. Both dont work for me. I've had the same problem while using type: integer and type: float. I've resolved those by using type: int and type: decimal.

I dont understand why its not working.

Comment: I think the end and start that you are trying to insert is in the format of string. Before calling any method like create or update try to convert that to new Date(start) and new Date(end) in javascript

Comment: Try to post in this format 2016-09-19T22:00:00Z. My guess is that sailsjs denies the date without timezone context but I might be wrong.

Comment: Alright, finally got around to test your answer. But in the end it didn't work. Both the new Date(start) / new Date(end) and ISO date string methods didn't work. Its an odd issue since it used to work before and sails should properly convert your given date to a ISO date string.